# Drag and drop over a given container

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a drag and drop in an `ImageView` of a container (eg `LinearLayout`) there are other components on the screen and would like to make the drop identified that specific container. If the drop is done elsewhere the 'ImageView' should return to its place of origin.

I have this code:

```
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import br.com.atlantic.albumshow.R;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        imageView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();

                switch (action) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        if (event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                            return (true);
                        }
                        return (false);
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                        if (v instanceof LinearLayout) {

                            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                            owner.removeView(view);
                            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                            container.addView(view);

                        }
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }

        });
    }

    float x, y = 0.0f;
    boolean moving = false;

    private class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(moving) {
                        x = motionEvent.getRawX() - view.getWidth() / 2;
                        y = motionEvent.getRawY() - view.getHeight() * 3 / 2;
                        view.setX(x);
                        view.setY(y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    moving = true;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    moving = false;
                    break;

            }

            return true;

        }

    }
}
```

I tried to use the various [examples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_drag_and_drop.htm) that use the `DragShadowBuilder` but its drop effect is beautiful only if able to identify the container and this drop was in a different location. In short, with the `DragShadowBuilder` could not do the drop in the identified container and remove the animation that has dragged the item to move to the place of origin.

I can use `DragShadowBuilder` to remove this animation if it is not the container (eg containerA).

I can identify the view I'm doing the drop.

If it is not possible with `DragShadowBuilder`, can I with that code identify the container from the drop?